# Inverting Fn + Arrow Keys

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey, hotkeys

I recently purchased a Samsung Notebook 9 and the special function keys (adjust brightness, sound, etc.) are mapped to the function key row and accessed either using the <kbd>fn</kbd> key or directly while the <kbd>fn Lock</kbd> key is activated.

Because I use the special functions such as the volume up key more often than the <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd> key functions, I would like to keep the <kbd>fn Lock</kbd> key activated by default. However, the arrow keys are mapped to <kbd>PageUp</kbd>, <kbd>PageDown</kbd>, <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd> when the <kbd>fn Key</kbd>/<kbd>fn Lock</kbd> is depressed. This is frustrating, since the arrow keys are used for their normal functions quite frequently.

How can I invert the function of my arrow keys only, such that while <kbd>fn Lock</kbd> is depressed the arrow keys function normally (Up, Down, Left, Right) and while the <kbd>fn Lock</kbd> key is not depressed, they function as <kbd>PageUp</kbd>, <kbd>PageDown</kbd>, <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd>?

Answer (score 4):

In order to achieve the desired result of inverting the function of the arrow keys while <kbd>fn</kbd>/<kbd>fn Lock</kbd> is depressed, you can use a program called [AutoHotKey](http://autohotkey.com). You will need to install AutoHotKey, then create a new script.

Directions from AutoHotKey Help:

> •1. Right-Click on your desktop.
> •2. Find "New" in the menu.
> •3. Click "AutoHotkey Script" inside the "New" menu.
> •4. Give the script a new name. Note: It must end with a .ahk extension. Ex. MyScript.ahk
> •5. Find the newly created file on your desktop and Right-Click it.
> •6. Click "Edit Script".
> •7. A window should have popped up, probably Notepad. If so, SUCCESS!

Inside this script, we will paste the following simple code:

```
PgUp::Up

PgDn::Down

Home::Left

End::Right

Up::PgUp

Down::PgDn

Left::Home

Right::End
```

Because we only wish to invert the function of these keys, we don't need to worry with finding out how the OS reads the <kbd>fn</kbd> or <kbd>fn Lock</kbd> keys. Instead, we tell AutoHotKey to treat PgUp (the command send when <kbd>fn Lock</kbd> is activated) as a simple <kbd>Up</kbd>. This is achieved using the basic syntax KEYNAME::KEYNAME.

By toggling the <kbd>fn Lock</kbd> key, you can now use the arrow keys for their alternative functions.